How does potassium hydroxide break down organic peroxides?
It is always recommended to store diethyl ether over potassium hydroxide.
However, given that organic peroxides form via radical reactions, which mechanism involving hydroxide ions will result in the breakdown of such compounds?

I don't think it really breaks them. Klaus mentioned here it maybe precipitates them as salts. It might also inhibit their creation.

In Boston University documents, as discovered by Google, the main peroxide inhibitors in ether are :  2,6-di-tert-butyl-p-methylphenol/butylated hydroxy toluene (BHT), hydroquinone, diphenylamine, 1-naphthol, stannous chloride, ferrous sulfate, polyhydrophenols, aminophenols, arylamines, and other phenolic compounds. KOH is not mentioned.

@Maurice It can't be a true inhibitor, but even smallest amount dissolved would somewhat influence radical reactions.

A paper from Western Sydney Univeristy states "Peroxide formation is accelerated by exposure to air, light, heat, moisture and contamination from metals."

Potassium hydroxide, $\ce{KOH}$, is a very effective desiccant, downright deliquescent. That reduction in moisture might be effective in slowing formation of peroxides.
(As a side issue, some reactions, such as making Grignard reagents, demand anhydrous conditions, and it's best to keep one's ether dry.)

Many metals have insoluble hydroxides. Consider some transition metals that might be catalytic to peroxide formation:

$\ce{Fe(OH)2}$, "Iron(II) hydroxide is poorly soluble in water (1.43 × 10-3 g/L)... It precipitates from the reaction of iron(II) and hydroxide salts."

$\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ is, "insoluble at pH 7," Ksp = 2.79×10−39.

$\ce{NiO(OH)}$, nickel oxide hydroxide, "is a black solid that is insoluble in all solvents."


By precipitating some metal ions from solution, $\ce{KOH}$ might slow peroxide formation.


Disclaimer
These are logical deductions, but I cannot claim they're the specific reason $\ce{KOH}$ is used.

Transition metals rather break down peroxides than make them.

@Mithoron, yes, they actively catalyze the breakdown of H2O2 (fast enough to power rockets)... but I don't know about ether peroxides; that was just a guess. The WSU article did not state which metals, and there are many (Astronomers will state everything after He.) Do you have an idea what might be a metal catalyst for ether peroxides?

Check Maurice's comment^ for ex.
